# Mediaplayer Doesnt play the Video, if it does the video is lagging and doesn't play after 10 seconds

Tags: android, audio, video, media-player, m3u8

I trying to play some streaming videos from some **streaming** websites. The urls doesnt not contain any keys that need to  refresh. Here is my problem. I'm playing the first url which is **a m3u8 url**. It does not show the **video** but I can hear **the sound**. After **5-10 seconds** the sounds goes away and there is nothing to hear anymore. Some other m3u8 files shows the video but it is very lagging. The video though plays **smoothly** on the streaming homepage.

Here is my code to play the videos: I can see where I'm doing wrong so please give me a hand.

```
package playingPackage;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import com.example.ptivi.ptivi.R;

/**
 * Created by peyam on 2015-07-20.
*/
public class PlayingVideos extends Fragment {
private VideoView videoview;
private String uriDef ="http://176.28.44.168:1935/live/_definst_/livestream/playlist.m3u8";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

public PlayingVideos() {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playvideo, container, false);
    // Amozghary as default

        videoview = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.vvPlay);

        String urlString = getArguments().getString("url", uriDef);
        Uri Uriplay = Uri.parse(urlString);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    try {
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(getActivity());
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(Uriplay);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            videoview.start();
        }
    });


    return v;
}
}
```

it killes me becouse ive been working on this project for a long time and somethings just breaks all the time.

Comment: Can you elaborate which device you are using for playback? Moreover, the example stream you use does not really use an 'ideal' M3U8 header.
Here the version tag is missing also the duration of the TS segments does exceed the defined target duration.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104301/hls-streaming-video-url-need-for-testing for a list of HLS test URLs

Comment: @FlorianPilz I dont know what you mean by "device for playback".  I will look at the link you sended and will come back with details.

Comment: I was asking which phone/tablet you are using.